# Apply a JavaScript function to all Array elements except the ith element

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

In one of my projects I made 3 galleries, I would like to put both of them on the same page in the same position, not at the same time, however. For this to be possible, I chose to create 3 buttons. When I click on the first button for example, the first gallery should appear (both galleries are initially on display:none), then when I click on the second button, the second one should appear and the one shown before should disappear, and so for each of the galleries. I made a simplified copy of the page to make the thinking easier.

In general, my problem is that I don't quite know how to apply a function to all the elements in an Array except for one element.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Galleries</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="gs.css">
 <style type="text/css">
  body{
   background-color:royalblue;
  }
  header{
   text-align: center;
  }
  article{
   width:95%;
   margin:auto 2.5% auto 2.5%;
   height:850px;
   background-color:tomato;
   display:none;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <button>Third Gallery</button>
  <button>Second Gallery</button>
  <button>Third Gallery</button>
 </header>
 <section>
  <article>
   <h1>This is the first gallery</h1>
  </article>


  <article>
   <h1>This is the second gallery</h1>
  </article>


  <article>
   <h1>This is the third gallery</h1>
  </article>
 </section>



 <script type="text/javascript">
  var button=document.getElementsByTagName('button');
  var gallery=document.getElementsByTagName('article');
  for(var i=0; i<button.length; i++){
   (function(index){
    button[index].onclick=function(){
     gallery[index].style.display="block";
      }
     }(i));
    }
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214409/javascript-get-all-but-last-item-in-array) might help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript assigning event handlers via for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247928/javascript-assigning-event-handlers-via-for-loop)

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate over all the elements and compare the `index` of the button with the `index` of the current gallery item:

```
[].forEach.call(gallery, function (el, i) {
  el.style.display = i === index ? 'block': 'none';
});
```

or:

```
for (var i = 0; i < gallery.length; i++) {
  gallery[i].style.display = i === index ? 'block': 'none';
}
```

This will loop over all the elements and set the `display` of each element to `none` except for the on with an `index` that corresponds to the clicked button.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/L7m329a6/)

```
var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
var gallery = document.getElementsByTagName('article');
for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
  (function(index) {
    button[index].onclick = function() {
      [].forEach.call(gallery, function (el, i) {
        el.style.display = i === index ? 'block': 'none';
      });
    }
  }(i));
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you, your code is working perfectly as I need it to. I still need to understand some details in it, since I'm a beginner, there are still a couple things I haven't really got the hang of.

Answer (score 1):

What you have done is almost right... Loop through the whole thing and when the particular element comes, do not do that, but I don't understand what's the use of closure here:

```
var button=document.getElementsByTagName('button');
var gallery=document.getElementsByTagName('article');
for(var i=0; i<button.length; i++){
  if (i != 2) // Make sure `i` is not equal to 2.
    (function(index){
      button[index].onclick=function(){
        gallery[index].style.display="block";
      }
    }(i));
  }
```

Comment: The closure is needed otherwise whenever the `onclick` executes `i` will always be `button.length - 1`.

Comment: Why are you writing code if you don't know what it does?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I tried your version of the code, still it does not change the outcome :(

Comment: About the closure, I am not sure what's the proper explanation to that, but if you try the code without closure, the "i" used in the for-loop does not apply to the gallery-Array, it only apply to the button-Array. so I suppose putting the closure is the programming's way to affect the "i" to all the different Arrays used in the involved block of code.